# Using CSS for displaying hidden item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple html code like this [jsfiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/jd1eb17n/2/) which display an `<a> tag` named `Test`. What I am going to do is when I click to this tag Test, a new div with the class name `surveySummaryMenu` which including 2 other `<a> tag` named `v1 Test` and `v2 Test`should be displayed. I do this by using CSS:

```
.surveySummaryList> .active >.surveySummaryMenu {
  display: inherit;
}
```

but i seems not working. Can anyone have an idea?

Comment: You need an onclick handler in JavaScript.

Comment: there's no jjavascript to add the class when you click on the link

Comment: Also there is no element with `active` class so your css selector `.surveySummaryList> .active >.surveySummaryMenu` doesn't work. Were you meaning to add some js that adds `active` to some element?

Comment: One way of achieving this without JS (if that was the question, hard to tell), would be the `:target` pseudo class in combination with an anchor link, https://jsfiddle.net/jd1eb17n/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this: 
JS:

```
<script>
    function menuButton() { 
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = 'block'; 
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" >
  <ul class=" nav surveySummaryList">
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:" onclick="menuButton();">
        <span>Test</span>
      </a>
      <div class="surveySummaryMenu" id="menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:">
              <i></i> v.<span>2</span>
              <span>
                <span>Test</span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="javascript:">
              <i></i> v.<span>1</span> 
              <span> 
                <span>Test</span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.surveySummaryList .surveySummaryList {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.surveySummaryList>.active {
  padding-left: 6px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.surveySummaryList .surveySummaryMenu a {
  color: white;
}


.surveySummaryList .surveySummaryMenu a:active,
.surveySummaryList .surveySummaryMenu a:visited {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.surveySummaryList>li .surveySummaryMenu {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1001;
}


.surveySummaryList> .active >.surveySummaryMenu {
  display: inherit;
}
```